# Find all Java methods using only one specific property of a specific type of parameter

Tags: java, intellij-idea, refactoring

We're in the process of trying to identify everywhere that a specific type of object is used only to get a specific property from it, and pass that property into the method instead.

I'm thinking IntelliJ IDEA's "Structural Search" might be a good tool for this, but I'm not sure how to formulate the search template.

A concrete example:

```
public class MyClass {
   public Long getId() {...}
   public void setSomethingElse(int se) {...}
}

public class SomeOtherClasses {
   public void shouldBeMatched(MyClass mc) {
     doSomething();
     mc.getId();
     doSomethingElse();
   }

   public void shouldNotBeMatched(MyClass mc) {
      doSomething();
      mc.getId();
      mc.setSomethingElse(14);
      doSomethingElse();
   }

   public void alsoShouldNotBeMatched(MyClass mc) {
      shouldBeMatched(mc);
   }
}
```

In the above example, if I'm looking for methods that only use `getId`, then I should find `shouldBeMatched`, but not be bothered with `shoudNotBeMatched` and `alsoShouldNotBeMatched`, because they do something with the mc object other than call getId().

Comment: So you want to find places where the argument of a particular class has a particular getter called AND where no other getter or setter is called AND the argument is not passed further along as an argument to another method? I suggest you get *very* clear on your rules. And I suspect you’ll need to use a language recognition tool such as [ANTLR](https://www.antlr.org/) or [JavaParser](https://javaparser.org/).

Comment: @BasilBourque, you've got the rules about right.  I was hoping there was a way to do this with IntelliJ IDEA's Structure Search.   It's a one-off task, so not worth doing anything as heavy handed as parsing.   We just have several hundred usages of the "MyClass" equivalent, so I didn't want to go through more than was necessary.

Comment: FYI, having recently discovered ANTLR, I have been shocked to see how easy it is to write a code analysis app. Open-sourced grammar definitions for various versions of Java are readily available. And ANTLR automatically generates the source code for your analysis app. You just edit the .java file(s) generated for the class & method in which you are interested, overriding the callback method. The creator of ANTLR wrote an *excellent* book making this very clear. ANTLR is surprisingly useful for practical tasks, handy for tasks beyond the reach of regex. Good luck to you whichever way you go.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm thinking IntelliJ IDEA's "Structural Search" might be a good tool for this

And it is indeed. The documentation can be tough though.

Let's check [Search templates, filters, and script constraints](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/search-templates.html) page. It goes as follows.

> Let's say, you have a variable that matches a method, a toString()
>   method. Then this variable is actually a PsiMethod node. Retrieving
>   variable.parent will produce a PsiClass node, and so forth.
>   variable.text then will give you the entire text of the method. If you
>   just need the name of the method, you can use variable.name.

It seems that the task can be done by choosing the right template and writing a corresponding Groovy script.

The template is called `methods of the class` and can be found under `Existing templates`. They provide `__context__`variable to be used with a script.

We have to be sure matched methods have parameters. It is simple enough, just put a count filter on a `$Parameter$` variable.

[image: Count filter]

Then we need to extract the name of a parameter of desired type and see if it is called in the body of the method. The following script will do.

```
def parameters = __context__.getParameterList().getParameters();
def parameter = parameters.find { p -> p.getType().getName().equals('MyClass') };
if (parameter == null) return false;
String parameterName = parameter.getName();
String methodText = __context__.getText();
String occurrence = "${parameterName}.";
String methodCall = "${parameterName}.getId()";
return methodText.count(occurrence) > 0 && methodText.count(occurrence) == methodText.count(methodCall);
```

Put it in the `$Method$` variable filter and verify the results.

[image: Verify results by pressing Find]

Comment: Brilliant. Finally understood how script works in intellij structural search